# Multiple lines of text change position of other divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix position of divs next to div that contains more than one line of text. Everything looks perfect when `entry-bot` class has text only for one line. I've tried playing with `overflow` and `text-wrap` unfortunately without any success.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/UjAZD/1/

Final effect should look like this: http://cl.ly/Qf3Z

Comment: looks like to me you just have to change your width from 192 to 150px on the div that has 2 lines of text

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is - the fiddle looks OK to me.  Can you post a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: @andi, this is what I see: http://cl.ly/QgGl

Tested on latest Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Ah, I see - it looked fine on Firefox for me before, but I do see what you're seeing now on Chrome.  Let me look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your cards are aligned by baseline, and that's why the one with two line description "pops up". Lets align them by top:

```
.category-view {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Card's bottom width doesn't include padding, that's why it is wider that the container. Lets switch box model:

```
.entry-bot {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Now let's look at [the result](http://jsfiddle.net/UjAZD/2/).